# I have a data structure defined as QMap<int,int>, how may I sort this by value?

Tags: qt4.8

I have a randomly generated a list of integers and populated a QMap with these values but i would like to get the QMap sorted by value

Answer (score 4):

This is a demonstration of how to sort a `QMap <int, int>` by value and not by key in qt C++.

The values of the QMap were extracted and stored in a QList container object, then sorted through the qSort method. The keys were also stored in a QList for themselves. After sorting is complete, the QMap object is then cleared and the Keys and values are then inserted back in the QMap container in ascending order by value. See solution below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qalgorithms.h>
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMap <int, int> dataMapList;
    //QMap <int, int> sorted = new QMap<int, int>();
    QList <int> keys; // container to store all keys from QMap container
    QList<int> values; // container to store all values from QMap container
    QMap<int, int>::Iterator h; // used to loop/ iterate through QMap

    // used to iterate through QLists
    QList<int>::Iterator i; //
     QList<int>::Iterator j;

     //inserts to QMap Container
    dataMapList.insert(1,34);
    dataMapList.insert(3,2);
    dataMapList.insert(2,32);
    dataMapList.insert(14,89);
    dataMapList.insert(7,23);

    h=dataMapList.begin();

     qDebug()<< "unsorted";
    //list out the unsorted values along with their respective keys
    while(h!=dataMapList.end()){
        qDebug() << "[" << h.key()<<"], " <<"[" <<h.value()<<"]" << endl;
        h++;
    }


    values = dataMapList.values(); // pass all values in the QMap to a QList container to store values only
    keys= dataMapList.keys(); // pass all keys in the QMap to a QList container to store already sorted by default keys

    qSort(values); // sorts the values in ascending order
    dataMapList.clear(); // empties the QMap

    i=values.begin();
    j=keys.begin();

    // insert back the sorted values and map them to keys in QMap container
    while(i!=values.end() && j!=keys.end()){

        dataMapList.insert(*j, *i);
        i++;
        j++;
    }


    qDebug() << "sorted" << endl;
    h=dataMapList.begin();
    //the display of the sorted QMap
    while(h!=dataMapList.end()){
        qDebug() << "[" << h.key()<<"], " <<"[" <<h.value()<<"]" << endl;
        h++;
    }



    return a.exec();
}
```

Note: The iterators for the QMap and QList were used to traverse through the containers to access the value and/or keys stored. These also helped with displaying the items in the list (unsorted and sorted). This solution was done in a Qt console application.

Comment: Just a comment in case anyone is referencing this thread like I did... The method describe above completely ignores any relationship between keys and associated values! It says in the comments that values get mapped to keys in the QMap container, but that never actually happens.

Answer (score 3):

In `QMap` by default the items are always sorted by key. So, if you iterate over `QMap` like:

```
 QMap<int, int>::const_iterator i = yourQMap.constBegin();
 while (i != yourQMap.constEnd()) {
     cout << i.key() << ": " << i.value() << endl;
     ++i;
 }
```

You'll get result sorted by keys.

Try to think about transforming your task to fit standard algorithms.
Otherwise, you can use this approach to get sorted your titles:

```
QList<int> list = yourQMap.values();
qSort(list.begin(), list.end());
```

And then, if you need -- get associated keys by calling method `QMap::key(const T &value);`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, depending on the exact case, is simply to swap the keys and values around since the keys will be automatically sorted by the `QMap`. In most cases, the values will not be unique, so just use a `QMultiMap` instead.

For example, let's say we have the following data in a QMap:

```
Key       Value
---       -----
1         100
2         87
3         430
4         87
```

The following piece of code will sort the data by value.

```
QMap<int, int> oldMap;
QMultiMap<int, int> newMap;
QMapIterator<int, int> it(oldMap);

while (it.hasNext())
{
    it.next();
    newMap.insertMulti(it.value(), it.key()); //swap value and key
}
```

Our new map now looks like this:

```
Key       Value
---       -----
87        4
87        2
100       1
430       3
```

Comment: this works like a charm, only one comment... Instead of using newMap.insert(), you should use: newMap.insertMulti() to allow having duplicated keys.